# Undefined Reference when compiling C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, include, header-files

My code is similar to this one, but the problem is exactly the same: I'm getting an "undefined reference to `Test1::v" in Test1.cpp and in Test2.cpp when compilling the program in VSCode. What am I doing wrong? I'm a bit new on c++ so I just downloaded an extension that made me a project in c++ automatically. When I run the program using Ctrl + Shift + B it gives me this error, but when I do it with the Code Runner extension it doesn't detect the .cpp files.

```
// Test1.h
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#ifndef TEST1_H
#define TEST1_H

class Test1{
    public:
        Test1();
        static vector<Test1> v;
        int a;

};

#endif
```

```
//Test1.cpp
#include "Test1.h"

Test1::Test1(){
    a = 2;
    v.push_back(*this);
}
```

```
//Test2.h
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#ifndef TEST2_H
#define TEST2_H

class Test2{
    public:
        Test2();
        double var;
};

#endif
```

```
//Test2.cpp
#include "Test2.h"
#include "Test1.h"

Test2::Test2(){
    var = 5;
    Test1::v[0].a += var;
}
```

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "Test1.h"
#include "Test2.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have **declared** the `static vector` in the header file, but you need to **define** it in a cpp file. Add:

```
vector<Test1> Test1::v;
```

to your `test1.cpp` file. You can learn more about `definition` vs `declaration` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1410632/1294207).

Also make sure you read this: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Thank you! That helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could prepend the class name to call the variable directly since it's static. So, you could do something like:

```
Test1::Test1(){
//  v.push__back(*this);       // previous
    Test1::v.push_back(*this); // now
}
```

in `Test1.cpp`. You'll then get a reference tooltip on your VS Code:

```
static std::vector<Test1> Test1::v
```

Which proves it's done.

Comment: I dont think this will work. You still need to define the variable somewhere: https://ideone.com/qRAHEI

Comment: @FantasticMrFox What if you try the same thing in constructor of the class?